# Is it necessary to add IRSA to aws-auth config map for the corresponding pod to be able to update kube objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, k8s-serviceaccount

I have a service running inside the EKS cluster which reads/adds/updates/patches different kubernetes objects across multiple namespaces. For this to work, I did the following:

- Create an IAM Role => `service_account_role`
- Attached `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess` policy to it
- Create a `ServiceAccount` inside the cluster which is annotated with `eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: ${service_account_role}`
- Create a `ClusterRole` with rules to give proper access for performing required operations
- Create a `ClusterRoleBinding` to bind the above created `ClusterRole` and `ServiceAccount`

On running the application, I get error as: `User \"system:anonymous\" cannot patch resource (403)` (Here I was trying to patch an `Ingress` object to update annotation using python kubernetes client using the method `read_namespaced_ingress`)

Next, I tried adding the `service_account_role` to `aws_auth` config map with group `system:masters` and the application started running fine without any issues.

So my questions are:

1. Despite having all the required rules setup as a part of `ClusterRole` which is bound to the pods `ServiceAccount`, why is it still required to map the relevant role using the `aws-auth` config map?
2. Isn't this map only used to access the AWS resources outside the cluster?
3. What is the `system:anonymous` group? I couldn't find any good source of information regarding this.
4. Is it possible to move the IRSA to `system:masters` without touching aws-auth config map? Patching this map concurrently is big pain which could happen as I need multiple services/IRSAs which would require such permissions.

Comment: did you tried attaching service account directly to deployment without cluster role and `securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
        runAsUser: 2000
      serviceAccountName: service-account-name`

Comment: @HarshManvar I already have `serviceAccountName: service-account-name` configured in the pod spec but not `securityContext`. Does `securityContext` have any impact on these?

Comment: Yes Give it try i also faced similar issue and security context resolves that.